# Call another template tag which uses @register.inclusion_tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using a custom template tag which calls another one, depending on which hour it is.

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def my_custom_template_tag(context):
"""
"""
now = datetime.now()

# if the current hour:minute is less than
# the publication switch settings defined hour
if now.strftime('%H:%M') <= settings.PUBLICATION_SWITCH_TIME:
    print now.strftime('%H:%M')
    return my_other_template_tag(context)
else:
    pass

@register.inclusion_tag('my_other_template_tag_template_path', takes_context=True)
def my_other_template_tag(context):
"""

"""
return {
    'foo'
}
```

the problem is, my_custom_template_tag seems to ignore the called "my_other_template_tag" @inclusion_tag. Is there a way to achieve this, while keeping using the @inclusion_tag ??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a slightly different problem, and wanted to render a templatetag in my views, so I wrote a helper function that would allow me to do that. A variation of it should also work for rendering within a simple_tag. Here's the helper:

```
def render_templatetag(request, tag_string, tag_file, dictionary=None):
    dictionary = dictionary or {}
    context_instance = RequestContext(request)
    context_instance.update(dictionary)
    t = Template("{%% load %s %%}{%% %s %%}" % (tag_file, tag_string))
    return t.render(context_instance)
```

It just creates a template on the fly that loads the proper tag file, and has the template_tag you're using. For use in a simple_tag, you can modify the function and replace the request arg with context.